# Android Fragments: Lifecycle method *always* called when fragment is displayed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to execute some code whenever a fragment is displayed to the user.

Looking through the API the closest hook method I could see for this is onResume. However, from debugging through my code it seems that onResume is **not** called when the user selects the back-button to return to a previously displayed fragment.

Just to clarify the behaviour I am seeing:

I have a 'parent' activity which configures tabs in an ActionBar... and 2 fragments F1 and F2.

The user selects a tab and F1 is loaded into the activity. On a button press, the user can navigate to F2. This is not a separate tab... F2 is swapped into the layout.

Adding log statements, I can see that when the user selects the back-button on F2, the following happens....

1) onPause() is called on F2.
2) F1 is loaded into the activity... but onResume() on F1 is **not called**

There are no errors in the logs at this time.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Neil.

Comment: You should always post your relevant code so we can see what is happening. Do you add each fragment to the back stack?

Comment: Thanks Sam. While editing my question and adding the code, I noticed my error was in my fragment switching-code. I've added an answer explaining. Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, it seems this one was pilot-error. My original code to switch between fragments in an activity was....

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment newFragment, String tag) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(tag)
            .commit();
}
```

The call to add() in the above code should actually be to replace(). It seems that not replacing the fragment in the activity messes with the back-button behaviour.

Have to be honest and admit I'm not 100% sure exactly why this happens. However, after making the change, the onResume() method is called on the destination fragment, once the back-button is called.

Comment: I don't have the reputation required to downvote. I would actually have upvoted you, purely for the comedy value of misspelling 'RTFM'.

Comment: You are a genius Sir!! Thanks a ton to save hell lot of frustration.

Comment: Now after 6 years, I can see Neil was screwed up at that time and tried to vent his spleen on @MarcinOrlowski. To be clear, you should have posted your "smartass" code to get a proper answer :))

Answer (score 0):

This bit odd question, because any existing class method is guaranteed to be called when event that this certain method was designed to be called for occurs and all the conditions are met. Choose any that  fits task you want to accomplish best. See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[image]

Comment: This is a bit of an odd answer as, in your rush to be smart, you obviously never read my question. And I did 'RTFM' (I assume that's what you meant) and the 'manual' did not help me. As I explained there is no life-cycle method I can see that is guaranteed to be called when a fragment is returned-to via a press of the back button.

Comment: All of the diagram is clear, as it is part of the Android javadoc's - however, it does not answer my question.

Comment: The side arrow is labeled "the fragment returns to the layout from the back stack". Choose any method after that point (best `onResume()`) and that's it.

Comment: As I said in the original post, onResume() is not being called on the back-button. onPause() is being called from the previous fragment, but onResume() is not being called on the target fragment. I'll add some more detail to the OP to make it clear.

Comment: onPause() should be called on current fragment and onResume() on the one that you are going back to

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski But If I am using `.add` in place of `.replace`, No Lifecycle method is called. Can you explain that ?